# print webpage in two columns

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to print a webpage in two columns or one column as per the user input/choice.

And when a take a print out I'm getting the website url on the top left side, How can we stop printing this?

Regards

Comment: Could you be a little bit more specific? I'm afraid I don't understand your question fully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When specifying a `<link>` (such as to a CSS stylesheet) you can specify a [media attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/styles.html#adef-media) so the CSS will only be used for [print or screen. (or braille!)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-media-descriptors) The CSS in this file can then re-style your site into columns as you see fit.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" />
```

You could specify two print CSS files like this, and - using JavaScript - prompt the user for which CSS file to use when they print, toggling the `disabled` member of the `<link>`:

```
var printCSS = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[n];
printCSS.disabled = true;
printCSS.disabled = false;
```

Answer (score 2):

With mozilla, you can use the `-moz-column-count` style:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd'>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Two columns</title>
  <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
</head>
<body>

  <div style='-moz-column-count:2'>
     one<p>
     two<p>
     three<p>
     four<p>
     five<p>
     six
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

It doesn't work with IE, however, and I don't think there's something equivalent for IE, either.

As for the printing of the URL, others have already pointed out that you have no control over it. The user can (and I usually do) in Firefox in the dialog `File` -> `Page Setup` -> `Margins & Header/Footer`: set Header and footers to `blank`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a style-sheet specific for printing and in theory that would allow you to print your content in 2 columns or 1, depending on user choice and how well your html is organized.

The address at the top of the print-out comes from the visitor's browser and I doubt you can turn it off at it is a setting that only the visitor has control over.

Answer (score 0):

The URL appearing on the page is a browser setting and cannot be controlled by script.

Two print in two columns, make sure your HTML uses [a print stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85019/how-can-you-make-a-web-page-send-to-the-printer-something-different-than-whats-i) and make sure your HTML can easily be reformatted in two columns using [floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156712/how-to-float-3-divs-side-by-side-using-css).

Answer (score 0):

> How to print a webpage in two columns or one column as per the user input/choice.

You *could* provide an [alternative stylesheet](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=css%20switcher) using [@media rule](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/media.html#at-media-rule) to provide a different layout that is only applied to print media … but I suspect this is better off left to the user's printer settings.

> And when a take a print out I'm getting the website url on the top left side, How can we stop printing this?

This is a browser preference. Authors can't remove it.